# Unable to update xml element value with ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

I am using below playbook to update specific element value in xml file and its throwing error. I have installed python-lxml module as well as ansible version 2.7.8

```
---
 - name: Set element
   xml:
     path: /home/emsuser/appD_agent_master/machineagent/machine_agent/conf/controller-info.xml
     xpath: /controller-info/application-name
     value: "Vicom Enterprise blackout Manager"
...
```

responce:

```
ERROR! 'xml' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/home/emsuser/playbooks/editMechineAgentConf.yml': line 2, column 4, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
 - name: Set element
   ^ here
```

I am not sure where I am doing mistake. Please help me out . I am new to ansible.

Comment: Can you update the question with the playbook editMechineAgentConf.yml

Comment: i think you are doing something like `ansible-playbook /home/emsuser/playbooks/editMechineAgentConf.yml` and thats not a valid playbook. See https://www.ansible.com/blog/getting-started-writing-your-first-playbook

Comment: First code block is my yml file .

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not a playbook, it's a task file.

In a playbook, you have a `tasks:` section listing your tasks.

Take a look at the [Playbooks intro documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-language-example).